# React-Native: How to define component based on device type

Tags: react-native, layout, components

From React-Native document, we can define the component in different file by adding .android.js or .ios.js. Is there a way to define whether the device is tablet or phone so i can define different layout of the component based on their type not the platform of the device.

Answer (score 0):

`import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'`

`let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width`

This code will get the width of your device.

Seeing how most mobile phones' [device width is 480 px or less](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml), you can add an if statement `if deviceWidth <= 480` for handling mobile phones, and use `if deviceWidth > 480` for tablets.